# Express js static relative parent directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently experiencing some minor problems with serving static files through expressJs.

My directory structure is as following:

- public

  - css
  - lib
- src

  - views
  - home

    - index.html
  - server.js

In my `index.html` file i have prefixed all my assets with a leading slash.

My static setup is as following:
`app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '../' + 'public')));`

But for some reason my static files are not getting served.

I was thinking that this is a crossdomain call or something...
I'm currently using cloud9 IDE, might this have to do with it somehow?

Comment: you should change the accepted answer to the other one, since the current accepted answer no longer works and was never the best solution.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should use [path.join](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) instead of manually concatening path components. It uses [path.normalize](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p), which resolves `.` and `..`, handles multiple or trailing slashes, and uses the appropriate file separator for your platform (see: [path.sep](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep)).

For example,

```
var path = require('path');

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Comment: UPDATE: since serving any `..` is explicitly forbidden in `express.js` (but serving any absolute path is perfectly allowed), in newer expressjs versions only this answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 61):

`__dirname` doesn't have a trailing slash, so `__dirname + '../'` results in `DIRNAME../` (which isn't valid).

Instead, use:

```
__dirname + '/../public'
             ^ extra slash
```

Comment: What a god-send! Couldn't figure out why my relative paths for the fetches for my static content were screwed up.

Comment: UPDATE: as we can see in `node_modules/send/index.js:508`, the pathes containing any `..` are explicitly forbidden in `express.js`. If your full path contains a `..`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399886/1783163) is your answer.

Comment: @peterh `path.resolve()` (which is being used here) will fix that already. Even it it wasn't being used, [`serve-static`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/b3a24df138ea2f2c43afcbee0dcce5badf4c78ae/index.js#L65) (aka `express.static`) _also_ calls `path.resolve()`.

Comment: @robertklep I use the latest stable expressjs and it didn't work, I had to track the error message. Monday I will doublecheck this again.

Comment: @peterh this answer may not work if you're on Windows (which the OP wasn't).