# Express Serve Static Files Outside of Server Directory

Tags: node.js, http, express, static-files

I have had to take over and finish a project done in Nodejs after a coworker left so I know what I have learned in the last 2 days, please excuse my ignorance if this is a simple problem.  I have a valid need (insert long unnecessary explanation) to serve a directory of static files that is completely outside of the project. I've tried

`app.use('/outsideproject', express.static("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\TheDirectory"))`

and it doesn't seem to work.  After googling around it doesn't appear I can do it in this way.  Are there any other ways?  I'd rather keep it all in the project for clarity, but I guess I could get IIS involved to make it work if needed.

Comment: This may not be relevant but it is worth mentioning just in case - you can use nginx to serve static files. I have just started looking into this so i am not all that familiar but there are a lot tutorials/documentation on it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was thinking the same idea with IIS as a backup plan.  My hope was to keep all the code together for clarity in the future and so it just works as-is, plus the third party software that makes this a requirement, without having to sort anything more out.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322480/express-js-static-relative-parent-directory