# How do I serve files from a lower directory with Express 3.x?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399886/9400421) made it clear how to serve files from a lower directory than the program's root, like so:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

This worked fine. Now I'm trying to set up a socket.io server like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

and socket.io is throwing the error:

> Error: You are trying to attach socket.io to an express request
>   handler function. Please pass a http.Server instance.

Which makes sense, because now on the socket.io documentation, it's asks for a setup like this:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```

But I don't know how to reconcile the old way of loading files from a lower directory like shown in the answer above with this new way of setting up express and socket.io, because where `const app = require('express')();` as in the socket.io documentation, the error gets thrown `TypeError: app.static is not a function`.

How do I reconcile the now-outdated express path routing with the new express setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way i did it in the old days of express 3.x.

```
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
/* ... more routing logic, i.e app.get(...)*/
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => {/* ... */});
server.listen(3000);
```

Hope it helps