# After using express static function, Css and image still won't load up

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

My program can't pick up on where the images and the css are located. tried adding a '/' before the "public", pointing to specific locations to get the css and image and nothing seemed to work for me. Here's my code:

**javascript:**

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html")
})

app.listen("3000", () => console.log("NEWSLETTER is running on port 3000."));
```

**HTML:**

```
    <main class="form-signin">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <img class="mb-4" src="./public/images/roundups-v0@2x.png" alt="" width="120" height="100">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

            <input type="text" class="form-control top" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="email" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="Email">

            <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017 – 2021</p>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

**Project layout:**

```
/public
    /images
        /roundups-v0@2x.png
    /styles
        /signup.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `public` from the filepath:

> ***Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.***

[Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

---

You might also consult this post: [Express js static relative parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322480/express-js-static-relative-parent-directory)